# Multiple errors with trying to wrap a figure

Tags: floats, environments, wrapfigure

I want to wrap a figure so that it is on the right side of the paragraph but when I try to compile it, I get these errors:

[image]

This is my code for that part:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\begin{document}
\subsection{Wheatstone Bridge}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Images/Wheatstonebridge.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}
A wheatstone bridge is used to \textbf{measure an unknown resistance} value to a high degree of accuracy. It uses 4 resistors set up in a diamond fashion (shown below) and a voltmeter. In the schematic below, R$_x$ is the unknown resistance, R$_1$ and R$_3$ are fixed resistance values (generally the same, but they don't have to be the same, also generally $>$1\% tolerance, but again, not always) and R$_2$ is a variable resistor (potentiometer, this is not always the case, see below). By \textbf{adjusting R$_2$ until the voltmeter reads 0 volts}, you know that the \textbf{ratio between the $\frac{R_1}{R_2}$ and $\frac{R_3}{R_x}$ is equal}.\\
Without changing $R_2$:
\begin{align*}
    V_G=\left(\frac{R_x}{R_3+R_x}-\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I have tried changing the `\textwidth` and `\linewidth`, but it still doesn't work.

This is what I have so far:
[image]
What do these errors mean and how do I get it to wrap the figure properly?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimum working example, something that others can compile.

Comment: Using standard article document class it works fine (without any error, any warnings, any bad boxes). For further help we need MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document beginning with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}, which reproduce your problem

Comment: please provide an example that demonstrates the problem, The message says that you are using wrapfigure in some enviornment but you have not shown enough example to see the context

Comment: but note they are not errors, they are warnings.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I can't reproduce your warnings. With the following MWE, where i made three small changes:

- add `siunitx` to write `\SI{>1}{\%}` instead of the `$>$1\%` (not relevant to your problem)
- move `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the end of preamble (also not relevant to your problem)
- instead of `\\` on the end of the (i suppose) first paragraph, i insert empty line (`\\` is not intended for such purposes. If you not like to have intended paragraphs, add to the your document preamble `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`)

With this small changes I obtain the following result  for one column document:

[image]

(one warnings related to use `circuitikz`, no bad boxes)

and for two column document:

[image]

(one warnings related to use `circuitikz`, one bad boxes related to adjusting of words `unknown resistance` in paragraph using hyphenation)

MWE used in my test:

```
\documentclass[12pt, 
               twocolumn,   %delete,if your article has only one column
               demo]{extarticle}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multicol}   % why you need it?
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % new

\usepackage{lipsum}     % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}   % had to be last in preamble
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Wheatstone Bridge}
\lipsum[66]

    \begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/Wheatstonebridge.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}
A wheatstone bridge is used to \textbf{measure an unknown resistance} value to a high degree of accuracy. It uses 4 resistors set up in a diamond fashion (shown below) and a voltmeter. In the schematic below, R$_x$ is the unknown resistance, R$_1$ and R$_3$ are fixed resistance values (generally the same, but they don't have to be the same, also generally \SI{>1}{\%} tolerance, but again, not always) and R$_2$ is a variable resistor (potentiometer, this is not always the case, see below). By \textbf{adjusting R$_2$ until the voltmeter reads 0 volts}, you know that the \textbf{ratio between the $\frac{R_1}{R_2}$ and $\frac{R_3}{R_x}$ is equal}.

Without changing $R_2$:
\begin{align*}
    V_G=\left(\frac{R_x}{R_3+R_x}-\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\right)
\end{align*}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Conclusion, your MWE (as is in your question) work fine, without any errors, warnings or bad boxes. As mentioned @David Carlisle in his comment, if you receive warnings, you not need to worry, they are only warnings, not errors.